# Xcode XCTestCase setting values for UserDefaults

Tags: xcode, userdefaults, xctestcase

I am trying to run a UITest in a XCTestCase class, and also set a certain value in UserDefaults to true. (There is nothing in my func setUP() other than the super call so I did not post that part.) But when I run the test and set the breakpoints in the given ViewController, the value for the default key is not set to the desired value.

The code looks something like this:

```html
func testSomething() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "someKey")
}
```